# Query Guava Table by Value

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am creating a Table from a CSV file with data consisting of user ratings for different items [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5XNd.png)

I use the following code to fill the Table

```html
Reader in = new FileReader(OriginalRatingDataPath);
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(in);

Table<Integer,Integer,Integer> ratings = HashBasedTable.create();
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    ratings.put(Integer.parseInt(record.get("userID")),Integer.parseInt(record.get("itemID")),Integer.parseInt(record.get("rating")));
}
```

How do I query the table to get users who have rated items 3 to 5?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

The point of a table is to allow you to access records by either Row or Column. So if you need to access by rating, the easiest method is to use rating as a column.

```
Reader in = new FileReader(OriginalRatingDataPath);
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(in);

Table<Integer,Integer,Integer> ratings = HashBasedTable.create();
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    ratings.put(Integer.parseInt(record.get("userID")), Integer.parseInt(record.get("rating")), Integer.parseInt(record.get("itemID")));
}

// Copy column 3 to a new map to prevent editing the table itself
// when adding columns 4 and 5 - in turn preventing a memory leak
// from indirectly holding onto `ratings` through the map
Map<Integer, Integer> usersToItemId = new HashMap<>(ratings.column(3));
usersToItemId.putAll(ratings.column(4));
usersToItemId.putAll(ratings.column(5));

// To get just User IDs
Set<Integer> userIds = usersToItemId.keySet();
```

**Option 2**

If the majority of your operations are going to be accessing the table by `itemID` and `userID` you may not want to make rating the column. In that case, you can use the [cellSet](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html#cellSet--) method and manually iterate the table. It's performance won't be as good but it will work.

```
// Your current code

Set<Integer> userIds = new HashSet<>();
for (Table.Cell<Integer, Integer, Integer> cell : ratings.cellSet()) {
    if (3 <= cell.getValue() && cell.getValue() <= 5) {
        userIds.add(cell.getRowKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stream via cellSet()

```
private String getRowKeyByValue(String value)
{
    return records.cellSet()
            .stream()
            .filter(cell -> cell.getValue().equals(value))
            .map(Table.Cell::getRowKey)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}

private String getColumnKeyByValue(String value)
{
    return records.cellSet()
            .stream()
            .filter(cell -> cell.getValue().equals(value))
            .map(Table.Cell::getColumnKey)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, thanks!